# Is COM wire the same as Neutral wire in AC?

Tags: voltage-source

I am reading about a thermographic camera installation and I found in the schematic this diagram which has COM terminal and 24V, I have that physically and I was wondering if the COM terminal is the same as Neutral? (I underlined both terminals with yellow):
[image]

The physical installation consist of two cables (So the COM cable is the same as Neutral wire):
[image]

Comment: No they are not the same

Comment: could you explain me why are not they the same? I can not figure out

Comment: why don't you measure the continuity between neutral and COM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the same as the neutral wire,  the neutral wire is for connection to the mains, the common wire is internal to the AC (HVAC) system.

However they serve a similar purpose. and there are many parallels that can be drawn.  so the "C" wire is not Neutral, it's just *like* neutral.

Typically the C wire is connected to ground inside the AC.
The R wire is the AC's 24V "live" equivalent.

The C wite is needed for wifi thermostats like the neutral is needed for wifi lightswitches,